# packing and deploy the VSTO Outlook plugin

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I created VSTO Outlook plugin. In my dev environment, it runs perfect.
How can I packing and deploy the VSTO Outlook plugin (outside my dev environment)?

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways for deploying Office based COM add-ins:

1. Create an MSI installer, see [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019) for more information.
2. Create a lightweight web-based installer ClickOnce, read more about that technology in the [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2019) article.